# Why is my RequestTimeout broken by the following configuration?

Tags: c#, nservicebus, saga

I have set up a Saga in NServiceBus to encompass some logical progression of events. Any of the events are picked up fine, and almost all of the Saga functionality is working perfectly, this includes marking a Saga as complete, retrieving Saga Data etc.

The one thing that was broken was my `RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(45))`. After much debugging, I found the following line to be the culprit:

```
configuration.EndpointName(AppSettings["Endpoint"]);
```

Having commented that out, and instead adding an endpoint in the `<UnicastBusConfig>` section of my `App.config`, it worked. Has anyone experienced this bizarre thing, or can anyone explain why, potentially, configuring that particular parameter would make my request for a timeout non-functional?

Comment: Mike this is not really a problem suited to StackOverflow since it doenst really have a definitive error. you would be better served raising this on the forums

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware